# How can I insert value into my sql database using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, variables, sql-insert

How can I insert into MySQL database from nodejs code, where I need a query which could bind my local variable. the below code shows the 'fps' variable. I want to insert that fps variable into my XML table? I have tried different types of insert query method, but nothing worked.

```
var fps = file.fieldname + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
console.log(fps);
let sql = "INSERT INTO `xml`(`name`) VALUES ?",[fps]
db.query(sql,(err)=>{
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log("file loaded in sql")
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: /home/cybrosys/Desktop/experience_project/node.js:65
                let sql = "INSERT INTO `xml`(`name`) VALUES ?",[fps]
                                                               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)

Comment: no @CraftyMonkey

Comment: its no working @CraftyMonkey